# Can't read HttpContext body in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a .net core midleware where i write to the HttpContext body and then i would like to read the body but it dosent work.

I am using .net core version 2.1.0-preview1-final.

First i write to the response:

```
await context.Response.WriteAsync("Test string");
```

And then i would like to read the response body. I have tried with this code:

```
var stream = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body);
var body = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

When i create the stream i get an exception with message:

> "Stream was not readable."

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] of the function to provide more context of what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: This hasn't worked in any version. The response steam isn't buffered, the data goes directly to the client.

Comment: Why do you want to read it back anyways?